# Onmouseover using Hyperlinks

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, hyperlink, onmouseover

I have a hyperlink and 2 pictures (one is the link's normal picture and the other is its onmouseover picture)

I can't figure out how to make the hyperlink's picture change onmouseover. I know I can do it with the 'a' tag but this tag doesn't support this : '~/Site/Page.aspx' so if I want to navigate through folders I need to use '../../Site/Page.aspx' which is inaccurate.

So how can I change picture with the asp:hyperlink button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't. Use css:

```
a {
  background-image: url(images/image1.jpg);
}
a:hover {
  background-image: url(images/image2.jpg);
}
```

Only use specific selectors for you case, of course.

Comment: The a-tag *is* a hyperlink. Hover was designed for hyperlinks in the first place, because they are the only thing that needed a hover (because it was the only thing that could be clicked) back in the pre-JavaScript days.

Comment: Niceeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

I'd also recommend the CSS route, however to ensure no latency with image load you could merge the two images into the one file with an image editor and use 'background-position' to switch the viewable portion of the image.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but a good addition. This technique is called 'css sprites' and not only gets rid of the latency, but also minimizes the number of requests to you server, because only one request is sent instead of two to receive the images.